# How to convert a shadertoy shader (with a buffer) to use in three.js?

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I am trying to use ShaderToy shaders with a Buffer in three.js. Such as [this one](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsyGzz).

I figure that I need to setup uniforms for iTime, iResolution and iChannel0 but I do not know how to combine/modify the 2 mainImage() functions in order to use in three.js

Comment: You'll have to render the first buffer to a texture with [`WebGLRenderTarget`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget), then use that resulting texture as your source image for the second buffer. You can follow [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=rendertarget#webgl_rtt) where it does something similar.

Comment: you might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-shadertoy.html) useful